# Grandma and grandson share birthday but with a twist

Tags: probability

Both me and my Grandson were born on October 10th. I in 1956 and he in 2008...he was born at 19:56 in the evening. What were the odds of that?

Comment: Maybe you told your grandson's parents when to do it.

Comment: These kinds of questions are unanswerable because they are far too vague.  Odds of what, exactly?  Should we include the actual dates in the event or just the time?  Should we account for possible errors in measuring the time?  Should the odds be conditional on the fact that you were born and that he was born?  Should the event account for the grandparent-grandson relationship?  What population should it apply to?  Should it account for the fact that 19:56 is (mathematically) a very special time or not?

Comment: A major difficulty with assessing how unusual an event like this is, is that these events are never specified before-the-event, but only after the event -- these are always data-generated hypotheses (see also p-hacking, data-dredging). Treating the hypothesis of interest and the data that led us to it as if they had arrived independently of each other leads to nonsensically low answers. Usually there's no good way of actually arriving at a reasonable answer to such questions (on occasion however we can sometimes figure out a way to give an approximate answer to such questions).

Answer (score 1):

In a world with 7 billion people (not counting the many more people who have died), and with a calendar with only 366 dates, the probability of such an event happening at least once was approximately 1.

See the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for calculations of various specific scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you two answers, depending on your purpose.

If you are looking for a rigorously true and statistically backed statement to tell your grandson how special he is and make him interested in numbers at the same time, my answer would be as follows:

If you take another person at random, the probability of that person have been boon in the same calendar year as you is roughly 1/365.25.

The probability of having been born in the time coded by your birth year (that is, 19:56 if you were born in 1956) is 1/(24*60), that is 1/1440. Here I'm making the simplification that your birth year encodes a time, which doesn't hold for people born between 1960 and 1999, but I think I can do this simplification because:

- Taking it in account would reduce the probability and make your grandson even more special, so we are keeping our numbers in the safe side.
- Since we are interested in grandmas and grandsons and I expect that most grandmas of 2008 born grandsons were born before 1960, the correction wouldn't be as dramatic as it my seem.

Then, the probability of a random person being born in the same calendar day and the hour encoded by your birth year is about 1/(365.25*1440), that is 1 on 525960.

Since grandsons have two grandmas each, only one on 262980 will show such a coincidence - and that looks as a tiny probability, so you and your grandson can appreciate how lucky you have been. Furthermore, this probability only holds for grandsons with two grandmas born before 1960; for grandsons with two grandmas born after 1960 that probability is exactly zero, so you can feel still more special.

Now maybe you want to stop reading, because my second answer will be about discussing how special is being so special, and I'm afraid @Kodiologist is right.

1 out of 262980 is a tiny probability, but it's no so tiny compared with the population of most countries or the population of the Earth. Therefore:

- About 13300 people on Earth were born in October 10th at 19:56 (of different years).
- About 25000 people on Earth may have such a date and time combination with one of their grandmas - although I'm overestimating the number here because I'm not taking on account that some living people have grandmas born in 1860-1899 or 1960-1999.
- That date twist is just one of several possible twists. There are a lot more people who can claim a similarly special link by other twists (e.g. same day, same hour, or twist between day and hour as February 10th and 02:10, and so).
- What would actually be very special is to have such a date twist with both grandmas. The probability to exist a person in the Earth showing such a coincidence is below 3%.

Anyway, don't forget to remind your grandson that he is special because of how much you love him, and that no statistics can account for that.